# In scipy why doesn't idct(dct(a)) equal to a?

Tags: python, scipy, dct

I am trying to implement JPEG compression using python. When I tried to apply the DCT, quantization, IDCT process for a tiff image, I found something strange for scipy.fftpack.dct/idct.

Since there is only 1D dct/idct within scipy package, I was doing this for a 2D dct

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import dct, idct

def dct2(block):
    return dct(dct(block.T).T)

def idct2(block):
    return idct(idct(block.T).T)
```

I tested the 2D dct/idct using a simple 3x3 matrix. I was expecting to get a True matrix with this test case.

```
a = np.random.randint(0,255,9).reshape(3,3)
print a == idct2(dct2(a))
```

However it turned out that after idct2(dct2(a)) the result was scaled by a constant factor compared with the original a matrix.

I would like to ask if there is a way to implement a set of 2D dct/idct such that after a idct(dct(a)) operation I can get the same output as the input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scipy's fftpack dct and idct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325795/scipys-fftpack-dct-and-idct)

Comment: Some trivia. Instead of transposing your array every time, you can do `def dct2(a): dct(dct(a, axis=0), axis=1)`. And `dct(..., type=3) == idct(...)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set scaling to `ortho` for both `dct2` and `idct2`:

```
def dct2 (block):
  return dct(dct(block.T, norm = 'ortho').T, norm = 'ortho')
```

also, you cannot expect the values to be exactly the same, but almost the same within some margin of error:

```
np.allclose (a, idct2(dct2(a)))
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to normalize `idct2(dct2(a))` and convert the data type to `uint8`. One option is to use cv2 for this normalization:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import dct, idct

def dct2(block):
    return dct(dct(block.T).T)

def idct2(block):
    return idct(idct(block.T).T)
a = np.random.randint(0,255,9).reshape(3,3)

# convert to uint8
norm_image = cv2.normalize(idct2(dct2(a)), None, 
                           alpha = a.min(), beta = a.max(), 
                           norm_type = cv2.NORM_MINMAX, 
                           dtype = cv2.CV_32F).astype(np.uint8)
print(a == norm_image)
# [[ True  True  True]
#  [ True  True  True]
#  [ True  True  True]]
```